# How to load all webview fragments on app start and never reload when user navigates?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

I'm trying to load all the fragments on the app start and they will never be reloaded even when the user navigates to different pages. Is it possible? The following is my MainActivity.java file.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        //I added this if statement to keep the selected fragment when rotating the device
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }

    }
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_inbox:
                            selectedFragment = new InboxFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_orders:
                            selectedFragment = new OrdersFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_notifications:
                            selectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_account:
                            selectedFragment = new MyaccountFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

EDIT:
This is one of my fragment: NotifcationFragment. Other fragments are almost similar to this one.

```
public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {

    String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
    private WebView myWebView ;
    private ProgressBar spinner;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications,container,false);
        myWebView = myView.findViewById(R.id.WebView3);
        spinner = myView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);

        myWebView.loadUrl("example.com/notifications");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient()
                                   {
                                       @Override
                                       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                                           return false;
                                       }
                                   }
        );
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);


        return myView;
    }

    // This allows for a splash screen
    // (and hide elements once the page loads)
    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            // only make it invisible the FIRST time the app is run
            if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
                webview.setVisibility(myWebView.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.setVisibility(myWebView.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var foot = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-wrapper')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-to-top-wrapper')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('new-menu responsive')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have implemented when the user switch between the navigation bar tabs it always create new fragments. Then it should be refresh. If you don't want to refresh each time user navigate between tabs you need to change the code as follows:

Define Fragments creation at the top in the class
Eg :
`private HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();`  (do for other fragments also)

Then in navigation view listener do as

```
> case R.id.nav_home:
>       selectedFragment = homeFragment;
>       break;
```

do for other fragments too

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mywebView;
private HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
private InboxFragment inboxFragment = new InboxFragment();
private OrdersFragment ordersFragment = new OrdersFragment();
private NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
private MyaccountFragment myAccountFragment = new MyaccountFragment();
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    //I added this if statement to keep the selected fragment when rotating the device
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

}
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = homeFragment;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_inbox:
                        selectedFragment = inboxFragment;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_orders:
                        selectedFragment = ordersFragment;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_notifications:
                        selectedFragment = notificationsFragment;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_account:
                        selectedFragment = myAccountFragment;
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();

                return true;
            }
        };
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much! The app now loads the same fragments without reloading it. 

However, each fragment has a webview that still reloads on switching. That was actually my main question. Is there a way to prevent webview reload and load all webviews on app launch?

Comment: But according to your code each time you create new fragment at switching between tabs, E.g:-     
                case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;                                                                                                    Can you try out with one-time new fragment creation as in my example and please let me know whether it works.

Comment: I've edited the question to include one of my fragments. With the changes you suggested, he built was successful. But each fragment is a webview. So it loads again if I navigate away to other fragments. I am looking to load all webview fragments and never load them again.